# lattice barchart include a space for missing data

Tags: r, lattice

In using lattice::barchart I'm attempting to use the scales argument to control the x-axis labels so that there will be a gap in the bars for missing factor levels. Here's some example code, but it doesn't do want I want. I create a second data frame that excludes the row for factor label "b" - that gets plotted. I then use the original data frame to define the x-axis. Can the scales argument be used to create data gaps in the bars?

```
dat <- data.frame(a=letters[1:10], b=1:10)
dat.sub <- dat[-2,]

lattice::barchart(b~a, data=dat.sub)
lattice::barchart(b~a, data=dat.sub, 
scales=list(x=list(at=seq_along(dat$a), labels=(dat$a))))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include `drop.unused.levels = F` as a parameter in your call to `lattice::barchart()`

e.g. `lattice::barchart(b~a, data=dat.sub, drop.unused.levels = F)`

Edit: I realise this does not strictly answer your question in that it does not use the scales argument but it may be a solution depending on your aim.

Comment: Perfect! I just didn't want to add levels with NA counts to force it.  This works for my need. And I now see that argument is documented in the help file. oops. thanks